# Ada.Containers.Vectors not working with GNAT GPL 2017

Tags: ada, gnat

I am trying to compile this code:

```
with Ada.Containers.Vectors;

procedure Test is
   type My_Type is range -1 .. Integer'Last;
   package My_Vectors is new Ada.Containers.Vectors (Positive, My_Type);
   Vector : My_Vectors.Vector;
begin
   Vector.Append (-1);
end Test;
```

`gnatmake test.adb` gives this output:

```
gcc -c test.adb
a-convec.adb:1553:33: missing operand
gnatmake: "test.adb" compilation error
```

The error message leads to this procedure in the stdlib's implementation:

```
   procedure Insert
     (Container : in out Vector;
      Before    : Extended_Index;
      Count     : Count_Type := 1)
   is
      New_Item : Element_Type := <>;  --  << here
      pragma Warnings (Off, New_Item);

   begin
      Insert (Container, Before, New_Item, Count);
   end Insert;
```

It looks fine. I don't understand the error message, what's wrong here? Is it a bug in the stdlib?

Comment: No problem with `gnat --version` > GNAT GPL 2017 (20170515-63).

Comment: Instead, I see `New_Item : Element_Type;  -- Default-initialized value`.

Comment: No problem with GNAT GPL 2017 here either.  (On Debian/Jessie.)

Comment: I don’t see this with any of GCC 4.9.1, 5.2.0, 6.1.0, 7.1.0, 8.0.0, GNAT GPL 2015, 2016, 2017 (on macOS).

Comment: @trashgod: Changing that line like this works. Looks like this file has been tampered with, although I cannot say how that happened.

Comment: The issue with this is the following. According to the Ada language standard, when you add a one element to an array, you have to use a positional operator something like `a : = (1 => <value>)`. In case of containers, when you add one element, you have to provide a value for the `Count` parameter, e.g., `Count => 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Looks like this file has been tampered with…

Summarizing the evidence,

- Multiple [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46411589/ada-containers-vectors-not-working-with-gnat-gpl-2017?noredirect=1#comment79781697_46411589) report no problem with GNAT versions going back as far as 4.9.1.
- The initialization marked `<< here` is a compile-time error, as the [*compound delimiter*](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-2-2.html#I1186) `<>`, named *box*, is not valid in an [*expression*](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-4-4.html) used in [*assignment*](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-5-2.html).
- Based on [*How `gnatmake` Works*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/How-gnatmake-Works.html#How-gnatmake-Works), `a-convec.adb` would only be recompiled if it were modified *after* the corresponding `.ali` file.

Going forward, you might

- Check the modification dates of `a-convec.adb` and `a-convec.ali`, found in the `adainclude` and `adalib` directories, respectively.
- Reinstall the compiler.
- Notify upstream maintainers if warranted.

Comment: The `New_Item : Element_Type;` code dates from 2005-11-15! and is still present in the latest GCC sources.

Comment: @SimonWright: I noticed the same thing the `GNAT GPL 2015` source dated May,  6  2015.